# S3+Cloudflare enable gzip

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, proxy, cloudflare

Hi you systems experts out there,

I'm using S3 to host .jpg files, and I'm using CloudFlare (not CloudFront) DNS + proxy with always cache page rule on.

According to https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168086-Does-CloudFlare-gzip-resources- and https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168396-What-will-CloudFlare-gzip-, CloudFlare gzips .jpg files that pass through its proxy.

However I've never been able to get those .jpg files in gzip form according to the Chrome devtools Networks tab.

What else do I need to do to enable gzip?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see jpg or jpeg listed on this page: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168396-What-will-CloudFlare-gzip-

Answer (score 2):

[jpg/jpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression) is already a compressed file format (as well as [png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression) for example) so there is no need to gzip further.

There are specific tools if you want to decrease the size of a jpg image and compress further but jpg as such is already a compress file format so gzip will not make sense (as well as with any other compressed file format : png, pdf ...)